# App terminates and can't work out why

Tags: ios, cordova

I've got a phonegap app that's been working for ages but suddenly I keep getting force quit. I can't say when it first came in (so I don't know what i've changed since it happens).

Basically the app loads fine then gets to a point after about 10 seconds when it force quits with no error.

What's worse, i'm using phonegap build so debugging is providing to be a right pain. I can't not do it in phonegap build as i'm too reliant on the plugins being used.

This is what i've managed to get out of the iphone console

```
Sep  4 13:54:14 Haydens-iPhone AppName[529] <Warning>: THREAD WARNING: ['org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect'] took '65.408936' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
Sep  4 13:54:14 Haydens-iPhone AppName[529] <Warning>: THREAD WARNING: ['InAppPurchase'] took '33.147217' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
Sep  4 13:54:15 Haydens-iPhone AppName[529] <Warning>: THREAD WARNING: ['Geolocation'] took '31.754883' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
Sep  4 13:54:15 Haydens-iPhone AppName[529] <Warning>: InAppPurchase[objc]: Getting products data
Sep  4 13:54:15 Haydens-iPhone AppName[529] <Warning>: InAppPurchase[objc]: Set has 2 elements
Sep  4 13:54:15 Haydens-iPhone AppName[529] <Warning>: InAppPurchase[objc]:  - newpet002
Sep  4 13:54:15 Haydens-iPhone AppName[529] <Warning>: InAppPurchase[objc]:  - instantpet001
Sep  4 13:54:15 Haydens-iPhone AppName[529] <Warning>: InAppPurchase[objc]: Starting product request...
Sep  4 13:54:15 Haydens-iPhone AppName[529] <Warning>: InAppPurchase[objc]: Product request started

Sep  4 13:54:15 Haydens-iPhone AppName[529] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: nil argument'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x2e8aaf83 0x39125ccf 0x2e8aaec5 0x2f22522b 0x2f225115 0x9067b 0x906ff 0x9406d 0xb9f49 0xb91af 0xb71f7 0xbb6e7 0xbb621 0xbbc5b 0x2f1eafc3 0x2f1eaf07 0x2f1eae21 0x2e5110e7 0x2e50fcf7 0x2e7de8f1 0x2e4a76bb 0x2e4a7579 0x2e4a740d 0x2e87620b 0x2e8756db 0x2e873ecf 0x2e7deebf 0x2e7deca3 0x33738663 0x3112b14d 0x9323f 0x39632ab7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I worked out what it was. Version 3.5.0 of Phoneagp doesn't seem to work with Facebook Connect plugin 0.4.0. I've written more at http://www.tiag.me/phonegap-crashing-suddenly-second-time-loaded-iphone/